# Adding a UIMapView Thumbnail with Pin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I've been trying to implement a UIMapView Icon like the one in this picture. Does anybody know how this app is creating that thumbnail?

**Edit**

Attempting to implement this with the following code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D restaurantLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Latitude, Longitude);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(restaurantLocation, 1000, 1000);

_mapView.region = region;
_mapView.hidden = NO;

_annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
_annotation.coordinate = restaurantLocation;
//annotation.title = _restaurantInformation 

[_mapView addAnnotation:_annotation];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_mapView.frame.size);
[_mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGSize newSize;
newSize.width = 50; // any width u want
newSize.height= 80; // any height u want
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[mapImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)]; 
_mapThumbnail.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation in Mapview with location should be in centre. Now

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.frame.size);
[mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

For creating thumbnail of mapImage resize according

```
CGSize newSize;
newSize.width = 50; // any width you want
newSize.height= 80; // any height you want
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[mapImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)]; 
UIImage* thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Another Way is

You can try [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example)

Here's sample code

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=200x200&sensor=false";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
UIImage *thumbnail= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[yourImageView setImage:thumbnail];
```

Through this you can get static image based on your coordinates.

Comment: I added the code I'm using for implementation in the question, but it still doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing this right? thanks

Comment: I've successfully got a MKMapView up and running, however your method of capturing the current draw and setting it to a UIImage isn't working...

Answer (score 1):

**This code for showing thumbnail of particular location and its working for me**

```
NSString *staticMapUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red|%f,%f&%@&sensor=true",lat, log,@"zoom=10&size=114x116"];
NSURL *mapUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[staticMapUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mapUrl]];
[imgViewClue setImage:image];
```